# Is it possible to do the form validation at client-side as well as server-side using HTML_QuickForm?

Tags: php, pear, validation

I am creating some web-forms with HTML_QuickForm. Now, QuickForm allows me to do either client side validation or server-side validation for a field. For example: If there is a field 'First Name' that is required, I can do this

```
$form->addRule('fname','First Name Required','required'); //server side validation

OR

$form->addRule('fname','First Name Required','required',null,'client'); //client side validation
```

Now to have performance and data-integrity of the data, I would require that the data-validation be done at both the client-side as well as server-side. So, is it possible to do validation for a rule, both at the client-side as well as server side using HTML_QuickForm?

Comment: HTML_QuickForm2 can do that, I velieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even when specifying "client", server-side validation will always be done. "client" adds additional client-side validation.

Comment: ok. thanks. I thought its just one way. Thanks for correcting me!